# Foreign key issues when copying an InnoDB database

Tags: foreign-keys, innodb, mysql

I'm wrestling with an InnoDB MySQL database & not having much luck (normally I'm a MyISAM guy).  I'm trying to take the content from a production database and copy it over the development database (e.g. same schema etc.. just hooked up to a different website).  Normally in MyISAM I would do this:

```
1) Dump the prod databse: mysqldump -u root -p prod_db_name > prod_dump.sql
2) Log into mysql terminal; 
3) drop database dev_db_name;
4) create database dev_db_name;
5) exit mysql terminal
6) mysql -u root -p dev_db_name < prod_dump.sql
```

et voila.

However when I do this in this particular situation all seems well until I try to update a content piece using the website hooked to the newly populated dev database; in which case I get this error:

```
Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`abbott/logs`, CONSTRAINT `fk_logs_user` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`))
```

Obviously this is related to the users table.  Although I'm not sure if it makes a difference, one factor may be that I am not in control of the user id's that populate the users table; they are fed in from an external Single Sign On / Federation API.

I've tried (blind guesses) adding --single-transaction to the mysqldump command; as well as set FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINTS = 0, then manually deleting each table & turning them back on again then reading in the dump (e.g. rather than dropping the whole db).

Any help would be much appreciated.
Reece.

Comment: are both the dev and production tables innodb?

Comment: yes; all tables within both DB's (even the newly migrated db) use the InnoDB engine

Comment: You have to set `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` to 0 in the beginning of the SQL file.